# How to filter nested object not equal in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Might be missing some simple syntax, but I can't seem to get not equal filter to work:

I can do

`filter: {property:{text:'yes'}}`,

but not

`filter: {property:{text:'!yes'}}`,

which does work for non-nested objects.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="attr in attributes | filter: {property:{text:'!yes'}}">
    {{attr.property.text}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.attributes = [
  {property: { text:'yes' }},
  {property: { text:'no' }},
];
```

Plunkr link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2mTcQijmfnqAM5vUtKsK?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the same effect with `ng-if` like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="attr in attributes" ng-if="attr.property.text !== 'yes'">
        {{attr.property.text}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you could write a custom filter that contains the logic or flatten the original structure somehow. I don't think `!` is supported in nested structures.

Comment: I don't know if it's a new feature, but there is a way to use `!` with nested structures.
Posted another answer with it

Comment: Ok, maybe they have fixed it then. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
filter: !{property:{text:'yes'}}
```

This is usefull in situations where you can't use `ng-if` like

```
<select ng-options="element in elementList | filter: !{property: {text:'yes'} }" />
```

(I know you can use `ng-repeat` in the options, but you get my point...)